# Your requirements could not be resolved: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: composer-php

I Need to install DomPDf in my Project. So, i add **"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "v0.7.0",** to composer require block. when i update composer display following Errors. Whats my Mistakes.... Please Specify to me..

**Terminal Errors**

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0-beta3 requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.4.* -> no matching package found.
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0-beta2 requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.4.* -> no matching package found.
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0-beta requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.3.* -> no matching package found.
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.4.* -> no matching package found.
    - dompdf/dompdf 0.7.x-dev requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.5.* -> no matching package found.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.7.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[0.7.x-dev, v0.7.0, v0.7.0-beta, v0.7.0-beta2, v0.7.0-beta3].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.7.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.7.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
```

**My Composer Code**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "v0.7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "uxweb/sweet-alert": "^1.4" 
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

but it display following error:

> Error : Using version ^0.8.0 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> file_put_contents(/home/w3cert/.composer/cache/repo/https---‌​packagist.org/p-prov‌​ider-2017-01.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've got the *Permission denied* error when running `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`, this is the command which should fix them:

```
chown -R $USER ~/.composer
```

or:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer
```

Then clear the Composer caches:

```
composer clear
```

After than try to avoid running `composer` command with `sudo` to not break the file permissions.

If there is still any problem, in order to troubleshoot, run the following shell command:

```
composer diagnose
```

Comment: Could you tell me what this commend does sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to install it from the command line

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

---

please delete this line from composer.json before installation.

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "v0.7.0"
```

Anyway the current version of `laravel-dompdf`:(v0.8.0)

Comment: I Already Tried. but Display following Error : Using version ^0.8.0 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
file_put_contents(/home/w3cert/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-01.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf 0.8.x-dev requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0].
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0].
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.8.0 requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.5.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[0.8.x-dev, v0.8.0].
@Ad NAN

Comment: So, your are facing a permission issue please make sure that the `/home/w3cert/.composer/` directory and its cache subdirectory owned by your user

Comment: You welcome, if the answer is acceptable please upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The installation should work with the current version of dompdf

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0"
```

Comment: Same Error Found... @Plxx                                                                  Problem 1
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.8.0 requires phenx/php-font-lib 0.5.* -> no matching package found.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.8.0].

Comment: I just tested the process with a fresh installation of laravel and it works just fine. Are you using the newest composer version (1.3.2)?

Comment: Composer Version is 1.3.0. How to Upgrade Composer Version.@Plxx

Comment: You can upgrade composer by running `composer self-update`

Comment: After Updating Composer Version Same Error will be Display. @Plxx